# Long input pattern validation fails on Edge and IE11

Tags: html, regex, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I am checking a email field to include any of the accepted domain names at the end using a long list of those TLDs in the pattern attribute of the 
`<input>` field

Here is a shortened version with the middle part excluded:

```
pattern=".+(\.aaa|\.aarp|\.abarth|\.abb|\.abbott|\.abbvie|\.abc|\.able|\.abogado|\.abudhabi|{...}|\.zuerich|\.zw)"
```

The pattern is accepted just fine in Chrome and Firefox but Edge and IE11 fail to validate if the match is somewhere in the ".co*" area and later

for example "email@example.aaa" validates, whereas "email@example.com" does not

Take a look and test here: https://jsfiddle.net/qoalu/Lj0p4ys5/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your regular expression is faulty. It failed .abbott and .abbvie but not .abarth, .abb, or .abc. Add a $ at the end between the right parenthesis and the quote. I tested it on IE and Chrome.